# Sending mail multiple times by Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Blazor server application**

- I have a web appliction that is using `AzureAd` and `OpenIdConnect` to login to this application.
- I am sending mail by using Microsoft graph and I am using the example in [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)  with some changes like this:

  ```
    @inject Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient GraphServiceClient
    @inject MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler

    var message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        },
        CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var saveToSentItems = false;

    try 
    {
       await GraphServiceClient.Me
        .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
    }
  ```

**Scenario of the error**

- This works perfect **but just for one time** , if I try to send the same email again it doesn't work and I got no error but just redirect me to empty page.
- If I logout and login again, then it works fine.
- The error that I got in the second time:

> Message = "IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. "
> MsalUiRequiredException = {"No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. "}

**My Question**

- How can fix the code up to send multi emails?. I think that I have a problem with token but I don't know where should I start?.

Thanks

Comment: This problem is easy to reproduce on your side, so please add a few more breakpoints to debug.

Comment: 1. When you are logged in, click send, we need to see the expected behavior when sending correctly.       
2. After setting the breakpoint, click Send again to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @Jason, I will add the error

Comment: @Jason, the accepted behavior is, I got the email in my mail box :)

Comment: Pls comment the code which used for sending email, and add something like `var access_token = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId).Result.AccessToken;`.   I want to check if I can still see the access token when I send the email a second time.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean!, The user login by `OpenIdConnectDefaults` in `Startup` page and the code to send email I wrote up in the question!

Comment: Change your code `try 
  {
     await GraphServiceClient.Me
      .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
      .Request()
      .PostAsync();
  }` to `try 
  { var access_token = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId).Result.AccessToken;
     await GraphServiceClient.Me
      .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
      .Request()
      .PostAsync();
  }`

Comment: Pls set breakpoint, and compare the access token in first time and second time.

Comment: @Jason, depends on what you wrote up I think that I have to switch to application permission but I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I think that I have to move the the permission `Delegated permissions` to `Application Permissions` like this:
[image]

**Why should I use application permission?**

In my case the user logged in for the first time and clicked on the button then the email will be send, **but** in the second time the application has to communicate with API graph without interaction from the user, that means without user and this exactly what I need(application permission).

**I adjust the code like the following:**

- Client credentials provider:

> The client credential flow enables service applications to run without user interaction. Access is based on the identity of the application. this is from [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider)

```
      private GraphServiceClient CreateGraphServiceClient()
      {
       // The client credentials flow requires that you request the
       // /.default scope, and preconfigure your permissions on the
       // app registration in Azure. An administrator must grant consent
       // to those permissions beforehand.
       var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

       // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
      // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
      var tenantId = "common";

      // Values from app registration
     var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
     var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

     // using Azure.Identity;
     var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
     {
      AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
     };

     var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
     tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

   return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
}
```

- Send mail with UserId, you can see the code in [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

  ```
  puplic SendMyEmail()
  {
   GraphServiceClient graphClient = CreateGraphServiceClient;

   var message = new Message
   {
      Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
      Body = new ItemBody
     {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
     },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    },
    CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
     }
   };

  var saveToSentItems = false;
  //See GetUserId down
  string userId = await GetUserId();

  await graphClient.Users[UserId]
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
  }
  }
  ```
- UserId:
  To get user Id you need `AuthenticationStateProvider`, this has to inject in the service of your application and then add to the constructor of your class, then you can use it.

  ```
  puplic class MyClass
  {
   private readonly MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler;
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationState;

    puplic MyClass(
        MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler,
        AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationState)
    {
      this.authenticationState = authenticationState;
      this.ConsentHandler = ConsentHandler;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetUserId()
    {
        var authSate = await authenticationState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        return authSate.User.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
    }
   //Here your 
   private GraphServiceClient CreateGraphServiceClient() { ...}
   puplic SendMyEmail() {....}
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Add the other catch block to retrieve the specific issue if we have any related to permissions or other ServiceExceptions.

```cs
try
{
  SendMail(); // Sending mail code here.
}
catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException e)
{
     // get the error here if we have any.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RajkumarPalnati-MT, this will not solve the problem, I know that I have a problem with token but I don't know why and how can I solve it because the first time I can send the mail without any problem.

Comment: Glad that you have cleared the issue. Yes, your right in your scope you have to use `Application Permissions` because we are not using the user credentials for the API call for second time, got it.